# Different results with the same code on a computer and a smartphone

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Different results are obtained with the same code on a computer(windows 10) and a smartphone(android).I'm working in P5.JS with used loadPixels(). Below is an example code and screenshots. I will also leave a link to OpenProcessing so that you can test the program:
https://openprocessing.org/sketch/1703228

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(300, 300);     
    randomSeed(1);
for (let x2=0; x2<width; x2 +=100) { 
for (let y2=0; y2<height; y2 += 100) {      
 
    fill(random(200),random(55),random(155));   
   rect(x2,y2,100,100);
     
}
}
///////
loadPixels();
background(255); 
for (let y1=0; y1<height; y1+=100) {
    for (let x1=0; x1<width; x1+=100) {
      let poz=(x1+y1*width)*4;
       
let r=pixels[poz];
let g=pixels[poz+1];
let b=pixels[poz+2];
     
fill(r,g,b);
            
  rect(x1,y1,100,100);
    }
  }
//////////
    
}
```

[Computer picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3S1z.png)

[Smartphone picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIiTs.png)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

p5js pixels array is different from the original Java's processing pixels array. Very different.

It stores all canvas pixels in 1d array, 4 slots for each pixel:

[pix1R, pix1G, pix1B, pix1A, pix2R, pix2G, pix2B, pix2A...] And also the pixel density mathers.

So your issue is with pixel density that are different from one device to another.

Try differents values to `pixelDensity()` in the code below. With 1 you get the result that you are getting in PC, with 3 you get the result you get with mobile.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(300, 300);
  //change here!!
  pixelDensity(3);
  randomSeed(1);
  for (let x2 = 0; x2 < width; x2 += 100) {
    for (let y2 = 0; y2 < height; y2 += 100) {
      fill(random(200), random(55), random(155));
      rect(x2, y2, 100, 100);
    }
  }
  ///////
  loadPixels();
  background(255);
  for (let y1 = 0; y1 < height; y1 += 100) {
    for (let x1 = 0; x1 < width; x1 += 100) {
      let poz = (x1 + y1 * width) * 4;

      let r = pixels[poz];
      let g = pixels[poz + 1];
      let b = pixels[poz + 2];

      fill(r, g, b);

      rect(x1, y1, 100, 100);
    }
  }
  //////////
}
```

To make them consistent you need to account for different pixelsDensity in your code.

the following code shows how to account for density using pixels in a determined area, in you case that would be the entire canvas.

To work any given area (a loaded image for instance) you can adapt this snippet:
(here i'm setting the color of the area, but you can get the idea;)

```js
 //the area data  
  const area_x = 35;
  const area_y = 48;
  const width_of_area = 180;
  const height_of_area = 200;
  //the pixel density
  const d = pixelDensity();

  loadPixels();
  // those 2 first loops goes trough every pixel in the area
  for (let x = area_x; x < width_of_area; x++) {
    for (let y = area_y; y < height_of_area; y++) {
      //here we go trough the pixels array to get each value of a pixel minding the density.
      for (let i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < d; j++) {
          // calculate the index of the 1d array for every pixel
          // 4 values in the array for each pixel
          // y times density times #of pixels
          // x idem
          index = 4 * ((y * d + j) * width * d + (x * d + i));      
          // numbers for rgb color
          pixels[index] = 255;
          pixels[index + 1] = 30;
          pixels[index + 2] = 200;
          pixels[index + 3] = 255;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
```

Comment: Thank you v.k. for such a detailed answer and for a deep understanding of the issue!